# How to declare MongoDB configuration in ".propreties" file?

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, spring-data

I'm new in MongoDB and Spring Data, usually the connection between an ordinary relational DB configuration is done in the `.proprietes` file such as :

```
# EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION
server.contextPath=/api

    # JPA
    spring.datasource.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    spring.datasource.username=postgres
    spring.datasource.password=root
```

But now i've migrated to MongoDB and i suceeded to insert an object in it however it is classically configured (in the main.java), and this is how it is :

```
public class Application {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "TestDB";
    public static final String COMPTE_COLLECTION = "Compte";
    public static final String MONGO_HOST = "localhost";
    public static final int MONGO_PORT = 27017;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

        try {
            MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(MONGO_HOST, MONGO_PORT);
            MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(mongo, DB_NAME);
            Compte p = new Compte("jon", "jon");
            mongoOps.insert(p, COMPTE_COLLECTION);

            System.out.println(p1);

            mongo.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And I want to know how to move the above MongoDB configuration to the `.proprieties` file ? I tried to put them as they are and it doesnt work.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Did you try [Spring Data Mongodb](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/)?

Comment: Do you mean the reference Document 'Spring Data MongoDB'? Sorry if I am getting it wrong coz it is new to me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see it documentation:

```
# MONGODB (MongoProperties)
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database= # Authentication database name.
spring.data.mongodb.database=test # Database name.
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy= # Fully qualified name of the FieldNamingStrategy to use.
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database= # GridFS database name.
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost # Mongo server host.
spring.data.mongodb.password= # Login password of the mongo server.
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 # Mongo server port.
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true # Enable Mongo repositories.
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test # Mongo database URI. When set, host and port are ignored.
spring.data.mongodb.username= # Login user of the mongo server.
```

Also from this link [connecting to mongo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb) note that:

> if you’re using the Mongo 3.0 Java driver. In such cases,
>   spring.data.mongodb.uri should be used to provide all of the
>   configuration.